# How do I make a recursive call with SQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, entitymanager, recursive-query

In my table a Person object can have relations to other persons. I would like to make a recursive procedure that returns a person´s relations, then the relation´s relations and so on.

I have a table with two columns, `Person` and `PersonRelation`.

```
PERSON         PERSON_RELATION   
id             id
name           person_id
age            relation_id
               relation_type
```

In my PersonBeanImpl I have a method that returns a list of a Person´s relations and also their relations and so on (recusrivly):

```
public List<Person> getPersonRelationsAndTheirRelations(int personId) {
     List<Person> relations = new ArrayList<>();
     getRelationsRecursivly(relations, personId);
     return relations;

}
private void getRelationsRecursivly(List<Person> relations, int personId) {
     relations.addAll(fetchPersonRelation(personId)); 
     for(Person p : relations){
         getRelationsRecursivly(relations, p.getId());
     }
}

public List<Person> fetchPersonRelation(int personId) {
     String sql = "SELECT p FROM Person p, PersonRelation pr WHERE pr.relationId = p.Id AND pr.personId = :personId";
     Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
     query.setParameter(":personId", personId);
     return query.getResultList();
}
```

This code works but it takes a huge amount of time to complete the transaction since the method `fetchPersonRelation()` is called many times.

Is it possible to do everything recurisvly with only SQL? I am using PostgreSQL.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c1f32/3

Comment: Yes you can use any of these: for loop, while loop and cursor in sql.

Comment: This isn't possible in SQL. The best approach is to retrieve all the data in a single query with `JOIN`s and sorting it by the values you need to associate, then manually processing it in your Java code. This will be at least 10x faster.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari You can use them in server-specific additions to SQL (such as PLPGSQL/Transact-SQL) but they are not part of the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: You change the order of Person and PersonRelation table such that time cost reduce.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Could you please provide me an example of how to make recursive calls with `joins`.

Comment: First, define the query to retrieve all the data you want/need. Second, have your classes to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Third, execute the query and use `Set` backed by `LinkedHashSet` to retrieve and bind the data.

Comment: Can you provide sample data on sqlfiddle.com? That way it'll be easier to write the example query.

Comment: @JakubKania: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c1f32/1

Comment: @JakubKania: updated sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c1f32/3. As you can see the resultset is 5 person relatives. Then I want to look at the relatives for each of the persons in the resultset and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [recursive common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). But they're a bit tricky so you'll have to make sure you don't get an infinite loop. But remember that for a big database it will mean pulling every record out of it ([Six degrees of seperation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation)).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am new to `WITH RECURSIVE` statements in SQL. How do I use the `personId` retrieved by the last SQL statement in the current SQL statement (make it recursive like in my code above)?